# Correcting mismatch in binary classification metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, roc

I am having an issue evaluating binary classification models. Using scikit learn metrics precision, recall, and roc_auc I get one set of values, but I seem to see different trends when looking at precision and recall against threshold (looking at threshold = 0.5) and the actual ROC curve. The code is pretty straightforward, and I'm struggling to understand where the discrepancy is coming from.

Here's the code to train and score the models:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score,f1_score, roc_auc_score, recall_score

#selecting models 
log_mod = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000,random_state=10).fit(X_train, y_train) 
lasso_mod = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000,penalty='l1',C=.05,solver='saga',random_state=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
elastic_mod = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000,C=.01,penalty='elasticnet',l1_ratio=0.2,solver='saga', random_state=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_mod = LinearSVC(random_state=10,max_iter=10000, C=.001).fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_kernel = SVC(kernel='sigmoid', random_state=10, max_iter=10000, gamma='scale').fit(X_train, y_train)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=700,random_state=10, ).fit(X_train,y_train)
et = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=2600, random_state=10).fit(X_train, y_train)

models = [log_mod,lasso_mod,elastic_mod,svm_mod,svm_kernel, rf, et]
#models = [elastic_mod, svm_kernel, rf, et]
model_names = [type(model).__name__ for model in models]

#scoring models
accuracy = []
precision = []
recall = []
f1 = []
roc_auc = []

for model in models:
    y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_predict,y_test))
    precision.append(precision_score(y_predict, y_test))
    f1.append(f1_score(y_predict, y_test))
    roc_auc.append(roc_auc_score(y_predict, y_test))
    recall.append(recall_score(y_predict, y_test))

scores = pd.DataFrame([accuracy, precision, recall, f1, roc_auc],columns=model_names,index=['accuracy','precision','recall','f1','roc_auc']).T
```

Here is a visualization of the result:

[image]

While that is great, these results do not match the observed behavior seen in an roc_curve or plotting precision/recall against the model threshold. Here is code for that:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV  

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
for model in models:
    #getting scores
    try:
       y_scores = model.decision_function(X_test)
    except:
       y_scores = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
       
    #cal_mod = CalibratedClassifierCV(model,cv='prefit')
    #cal_mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #y_scores = cal_mod.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] #https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html

    #calculating precision, recall, false positive rate, true positive rate, and normalizing thresholds
    fpr,tpr,thresholds=roc_curve(y_test, y_scores)
    precisions, recalls, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_scores)
    thresholds = (thresholds-min(thresholds))/(max(thresholds)-min(thresholds)) #rescale all thresholds

    #plotitng precision
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.plot(thresholds, precisions[:-1],label=type(model).__name__)
    plt.ylabel('Precision')

    #plotting recall
    plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.plot(thresholds, recalls[:-1],label=type(model).__name__)
    plt.ylabel("Recall")
    plt.xlabel("Threshold")

    #plotting ROC
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label=type(model).__name__)
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate (Fall Out)')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (Recall)')
    plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
```

Here is the output of this code:
[image]

The problem I have is that the order of precision and recall against threshold doesn't match the precision/recall metrics. We see ExtraTreesClassifier as having the best precision and among the worst recall at a threshold of 0.5, while it is shown to have the best recall and average precision from the sci-kit learn metrics above. Similarly, the ROC curve indicates that ExtraTreesClassifier should have a low-mid ranking auc score, but instead, it is the top performer in the scikit-learn metrics. These contradictions are apparent for all of the models.

I have used a min-max scaled threshold to account for the fact that different models have different threshold ranges. I have also experimented with calibrating the probabilities (this is commented out). I do not believe that either of these modifications accounts for the discrepancy I am seeing, and in either case, neither changes the ROC curve.

I am wondering what could cause this kind of mismatch. Any input would be greatly appreciated.